# Issue with ntheorem and \eqref

Tags: equations, ntheorem

Whenever I try and label an equation in the following format

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:blah}
blah
\end{equation}
```

and then reference this equation

```
By \eqref{eq:blah}
```

I get the usual (??) of an ill-defined labeling. It only happens with equation environments though.

I've tried removing almost everything I can think of in my preamble to make it work, but to no avail.

Consequently, I am posting a MWE which is not very minimal—apologies!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym,verbatim,url,color,mathrsfs,tikz,extarrows,enumerate,lipsum,mathtools}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumerate,fancyhdr,verbatim,comment}

\usepackage{dsfont}


\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}


\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}




\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newcounter{dummy} 
\numberwithin{dummy}{chapter}



\theoremprework{\setlength
\theorempreskipamount{10 pt}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{10 pt}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{example}[dummy]{Example}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:example}
\int_a^b f(x)\, dx=F(b)-F(a)
\end{equation}

By Equation \eqref{eq:example}

\end{document}
```

New MWE:

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,verbatim,url,color,mathrsfs,tikz,extarrows,enumerate,lipsum,mathtools}

\usepackage{enumerate,fancyhdr,verbatim,comment}

\usepackage{dsfont}


\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}


\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
 \newcounter{dummy} 
    \numberwithin{dummy}{chapter}



    \theoremprework{\setlength
    \theorempreskipamount{10 pt}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{10 pt}}

    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \theoremsymbol{}
    \theoremseparator{:}
    \newtheorem{example}[dummy]{Example}



    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:example}
    \int_a^b f(x)\, dx=F(b)-F(a)
    \end{equation}

    By Equation \eqref{eq:example}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: The packages are loaded in the wrong order: load all of them before `hyperref` except `cleveref` which must be last.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! It didn't actually seem to fix anything though. :( I have edited the above with how I interpreted your statement (plus what I read in the linked post). Am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: @egreg Nope, I figured it out. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Indeed this not a duplicate of the linked question.  You need to pass the `amsmath` option to `thmtools`.

Comment: Do you really need all those packages? Some of them are loaded twice. As I see, problematic are two of them: `extarrows` and `comment`. Both are not connected to the problem which you indicate in the question title.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Hadn't I already done this? This was one of the things I found when googling this problem, but I thought that \usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem} fixes the problem?

Comment: @Zarko To be honest, I don't know. I am, unfortunately, a very utilitarian user of LaTeX. Much of my preamble is copy and pasted from document to document, and came as part of some code someone else sent me, or that I copied from the internet. Why are the two you mentioned problematic? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @AlexYoucis, I will make an answer, by which I will show, that your MWE in case that you omit mentioned packages work.

Comment: Your first code has the `amsmath` option, your second doesn't

Comment: @AndrewSwann Oh, sorry! That was an issue in transcription. I'll fix that in an edit. Thanks!

Comment: Well now you have added an option `amsthm`, but the one you need is `amsmath`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann It's 3:14—i.e. another transcription error. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Since the final MWE works flawlessly with TeX Live from 2012 to the most recent 2015, I'm voting this as off-topic. The first MWE is wrong in that it loads `ntheorem` after `hyperref` (it should go before it) and `cleveref` before `hyperref` (it should go after it).

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, problematic are packages `axtarrows` and `comment`. They cause errors even if `ntheorem` as well as `equation` with referencing is not presented. Both clashes also with some other packages, what I didn't further investigate. Do you really need those packages in your text?

I suggest to load your packages in grops with similar use (math, etc). I made this according to my taste/habits. So, after this the code of your MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,latexsym,
                color,mathrsfs}
    % amsfont is load by amsmath and amsmath by maththools
    % url is also part of hypperref package, no need to be loaded
    % verbatim enumerate are loaded twice
    % extarrows make troubles, I suggest to omit it, most its functionality is achievable by mathtools
    % tikz and lipsum I moved in new group of packages

    \usepackage{enumerate,fancyhdr,verbatim}
    % comment make troubles, in all my needs is sufficient to use \begin{comment} ... \end{comment} from verbatim package
     \usepackage{lipsum}% produce dummy text

     \usepackage{dsfont}
     \usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}

     \usepackage{tikz}% for drawing pictures
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

    \usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newcounter{dummy}
    \numberwithin{dummy}{chapter}

    \theoremprework{\setlength
    \theorempreskipamount{10 pt}\setlength\theorempostskipamount{10 pt}}

    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
    \theoremsymbol{$\square$}% you not use a symbol for end of example
    \theoremseparator{:}
    \newtheorem{example}[dummy]{Example}

    \usepackage[colorlinks = true,
                linkcolor = blue,
                urlcolor  = blue,
                citecolor = blue,
                anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
    \usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\int_a^b f(x)\, dx=F(b)-F(a)
    \end{equation}
By Equation \eqref{eq:1} \dots
\begin{example}
Let explain \eqref{eq:1} with \dots
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\int_a^b f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = F(b)-F(a)
    \end{equation}
\end{example}
Regarding \eqref{eq:2} \dots
    \end{document}
```

With above MWE I haven't any problem when I compile it:

[image]